# Can we shed some definitive light on how python packaging and import works?

Tags: python, packaging

I had my fair chance of getting through the python management of modules, and every time is a challenge: packaging is not what people do every day, and it becomes a burden to learn, and a burden to remember, even when you actually do it, since this happens normally once.

I would like to collect here the definitive overview of how import, package management and distribution works in python, so that this question becomes the definitive explanation for all the magic that happens under the hood. Although I understand the broad level of the question, these things are so intertwined that any focused answer will not solve the main problem: understand how all works, what is outdated, what is current, what are just alternatives for the same task, what are the quirks.

The list of keywords to refer to is the following, but this is just a sample out of the bunch. There's a lot more and you are welcome to add additional details.

- PyPI
- setuptools / Distribute
- distutils
- eggs
- egg-link
- pip
- zipimport
- site.py
- site-packages
- .pth files
- virtualenv
- handling of compiled modules in eggs (with and without installation via easy_install)
- use of get_data()
- pypm
- [bento](http://cournape.github.com/Bento/)
- [PEP 376](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0376/)
- the cheese shop
- eggsecutable

Linking to other answers is probably a good idea. As I said, this question is for the high-level overview.

Comment: What's wrong with http://docs.python.org/distutils/index.html?

Comment: @Lott : that it explains only distutils, and it's way too long. I want the short story here.

Comment: @Stefano Borini: I doubt there is a "short" story.   Can you define what this "short" story would look like?  You've listed 13 things which are not very closely related.  What are you expecting?  Can provide some kind of outline or hint as to what a "short" story might look like for all these topics?

Comment: @Lott : Question: how can they be "not very closely related" but you proposed a single link as a solution ?

Comment: @Stefano Borini: I did not propose a single link as a solution.  I asked a question.  You answered.  I still don't get the list of topics.  So I asked another question.  I'm hoping for more clarification.

Comment: p.s. You forgot distribute. (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute) If you'll notice there these tools are all related and are based off distutils which is part of the standard library.

Comment: Competition is a good thing.  It leads to innovation and ultimately a better solution.

Comment: @AJ : I don't fully agree. Too much competition leads to suboptimal solutions, waste of manpower and a general sense of frustration. More to the point : http://forthescience.org/blog/2009/09/17/less-is-more-limiting-choices-grants-better-freedom/

Comment: @Stefano, can I suggest you kick off proceedings with an answer of your own about a particular experience with one of these. e.g. distutils!

Comment: @Stefano Borini - I agree that there must be a "sweet spot".  Do you think that among the various packaging solutions enumerated in your question that a subset of them are superior?  If so, why not lead with your own opinion here?  Once you do so, my guess is the debate will focus less on whether this is a valid question, and more on what you intended to ask originally.

Comment: @amir75 may do... but I'm actually trying to solve another problem at the moment...

Comment: You forgot Cheese Shop. You can get Python Eggs in a Cheese Shop.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the most part, this is an attempt to look at the packaging/distribution side, not the mechanics of `import`.  Unfortunately, packaging is the place where Python provides way more than one way to do it.  I'm just trying to get the ball rolling, hopefully others will help fill what I miss or point out mistakes.

First of all there's some messy terminology here.  A directory containing an `__init__.py` file is a package.  However, most of what we're talking about here are specific versions of packages published on PyPI, one of it's mirrors, or in a vendor specific package management system like Debian's Apt, Redhat's Yum, Fink, Macports, Homebrew, or ActiveState's pypm.

These published packages are what folks are trying to call "Distributions" going forward in an attempt to use "Package" only as the Python language construct.  You can see some of that usage in [PEP-376](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0376/#how-distributions-are-installed) [PEP-376](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0376/#how-distributions-are-installed).

Now, your list of keywords relate to several different aspects of the Python Ecosystem:

### Finding and publishing python distributions:

- PyPI (aka the cheese shop)
- PyPI Mirrors
- Various package management tools / systems: apt, yum, fink, macports, homebrew
- pypm (ActiveState's alternative to PyPI)

The above are all services that provide a place to publish Python distributions in various formats.  Some, like PyPI mirrors and apt / yum repositories can be run on your local machine or within your companies network but folks typically use the official ones.  Most, if not all provide a tool (or multiple tools in the case of PyPI) to help find and download distributions.

### Libraries used to create and install distributions:

- `setuptools` / Distribute
- `distutils`

Distutils is the standard infrastructure on which Python packages are compiled and built into distributions.  There's a ton of functionality in `distutils` but most folks just know:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='Distutils',
      version='1.0',
      description='Python Distribution Utilities',
      author='Greg Ward',
      author_email='gward@python.net',
      url='http://www.python.org/sigs/distutils-sig/',
      packages=['distutils', 'distutils.command'],
 )
```

And to some extent that's a most of what you need.  With the prior 9 lines of code you have enough information to install a pure Python package and also the minimal metadata required to publish that package a distribution on PyPI.

Setuptools provides the hooks necessary to support the Egg format and all of it's features and foibles.  Distribute is an alternative to Setuptools that adds some features while trying to be mostly backwards compatible.  I believe Distribute is going to be included in Python 3 as the successor to Distutil's `from distutils.core import setup`.

Both Setuptools and Distribute provide a custom version of the `distutils` setup command
that does useful things like support the Egg format.

### Python Distribution Formats:

- source
- [eggs](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PythonEggs)

Distributions are typically provided either as source archives (tarball or zipfile).  The standard way to install a source distribution is by downloading and uncompressing the archive and then running the `setup.py` file inside.

For example, the following will download, build, and install the Pygments syntax highlighting library:

```
curl -O -G http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/P/Pygments/Pygments-1.4.tar.gz
tar -zxvf Pygments-1.4.tar.gz
cd Pygments-1.4
python setup.py build
sudo python setup.py install
```

Alternatively you can download the Egg file and install it.  Typically this is accomplished by using easy_install or pip:

```
sudo easy_install pygments
or 
sudo pip install pygments
```

[Eggs](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PythonEggs) were inspired by Java's Jarfiles and they have quite a few features you should read about [here](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PythonEggs)

### Python Package Formats:

- uncompressed directories
- zipimport (zip compressed directories)

A normal python package is just a directory containing an `__init__.py` file and an arbitrary number of additional modules or sub-packages.  Python also has support for finding and loading source code within *.zip files as long as they are included on the `PYTHONPATH` (`sys.path`).

### Installing Python Packages:

- `easy_install`: the original egg installation tool, depends on `setuptools`
- `pip`: currently the most popular way to install python packages.  Similar to `easy_install` but more flexible and has some nice features like requirements files to help document dependencies and reproduce deployments.
- `pypm`, `apt`, `yum`, fink, etc

### Environment Management / Automated Deployment:

- `bento`
- `buildout`
- `virtualenv` (and `virtualenvwrapper`)

The above tools are used to help automate and manage dependencies for a Python project.  Basically they give you tools to describe what distributions your application requires and automate the installation of those specific versions of your dependencies.

### Locations of Packages / Distributions:

- site-packages
- `PYTHONPATH`
- the current working directory (depends on your OS and environment settings)

By default, installing a python distribution is going to drop it into the site-packages directory.  That directory is usually something like `/usr/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages`.

A simple programmatic way to find your site-packages directory:

```
from distuils import sysconfig
print sysconfig.get_python_lib()
```

### Ways to modify your PYTHONPATH:

Python's import statement will only find packages that are located in one of the directories included in your `PYTHONPATH`.

You can inspect and change your path from within Python by accessing:

```
import sys
print sys.path
sys.path.append("/home/myname/lib")
```

Besides that, you can set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable like you would any other environment variable on your OS or you could use:

- .pth files: *.pth files located in directories that are already on your `PYTHONPATH` are read and each line of the *.pth file is added to your `PYTHONPATH`.  Basically any time you would copy a package into a directory on your `PYTHONPATH` you could instead create a `mypackages.pth`.  Read more about *.pth files:  [site module](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html)
- egg-link files: [Internal structure of python eggs](http://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/trunk/setuptools/doc/formats.txt) they are a cross platform alternative to symbolic links.  Creating an egg link file is similar to creating a pth file.
- `site.py` modifications

To add the above `/home/myname/lib` to site-packages with a *.pth file you'd create a *.pth file.  The name of the file doesn't matter but you should still probably choose something sensible.

Let's create `myname.pth`:

```
# myname.pth
/home/myname/lib
```

That's it.  Drop that into `sysconfig.get_python_lib()` on your system or any other directory in your `PYTHONPATH` and `/home/myname/lib` will be added to the path.

Comment: Python3.3 adds [`packaging`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/packaging.html#module-packaging) module (It is available as `pip install distutils2` on Python <3.3)

Answer (score 3):

For packaging question, this should help http://guide.python-distribute.org/

For import, the old article from Fredrik Lundh http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm still a very good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [Tarek Ziadek's Book on Python.](https://www.packtpub.com/expert-python-programming/book) There's a chapter dedicated to packaging and distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `import` needs to be explored (Python's namespacing and importing functionality is intuitive IMHO).

I use `pip` exclusively now. I haven't run into any issues with it.

However, the topic of packaging and distribution is something worth exploring. Instead of giving a lengthy answer, I will say this:

I learned how to package and distribute my own "packages" by simply copying how Pylons or many other open-source packages do it. I then combined that sort-of template with reading up of the docs to flesh it out even further and have come up with a solid distribution method.

When you grok package management and distribution for python (distutils and pypi) it's actually quite powerful. I like it a lot.

[edit]

I also wanted to add in a bit about virtualenv. USE IT. I create a virtualenv for every project and I always use `--no-site-packages`; I install all the packages I need for that particular project (even if it's something common amongst them all, like `lxml`) inside the virtualev. It keeps everything isolated and it's much easier for me to maintain the grouping in my head (rather than trying to keep track of what's where and for which version of python!)

[/edit]

Comment: `I don't think import needs to be explored`. I disagree. There's a lot of "dark magic" (if you don't know the chain of events) when it comes to importing zip files, importing namespaced packages, importing eggs, pth files and so on.