# python & django_registration:: pointing to verion 0.7 when it is in fact 0.8

Tags: python, django

so i am using django and the django_registration module.

When i visit a page, I get this error:

> zipimport: can not open file C:\development\python\lib\site-packages\django_registration-0.7-py2.7.egg

with

> Python Path:
>   ['C:\development\PyCharm\helpers\pycharm',
>
> 'C:\development\python\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg',
>
> ...
>
> 'C:\development\python\lib\site-packages\django_registration-0.7-py2.7.egg',
>
> ...]

Where you'll notice the fourth line is referring to the 0.7 version!

The problem is, i am not using that version of django_registration. I am using the 0.8 version. What had happened was that, on my windows machine, i used the easy_install django_registration command, which got me version 0.7, but only as an egg file. It didn't make a directory or anything like that.

So i removed that by using easy_install -m django_registration
For good measure, i deleted the django_registration_0.7.egg file (or whatever it was called, that name isn't precise)

Then i went and manually downloaded the 0.8 version of django_registration from the main django_registration page: 
https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/downloads

And then ran the python build and install commands. However, now my python seems to think it is using version 0.7!

So, i suppose the questions are:
how do i find where this python path is being set?
how do I tell django to use 0.8, not 0.7?

Incidentally, I don't have any funky "pythonpath" environment variables set, and i'm on windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh.

I *think* the situation resolved itself, but boy did it take time.

the problem was that, for whatever reason, easy-install wasn't picking up the 0.8 version, but the 0.7 version. I waited a few weeks - i had other things to do than dig through the python classpath - and then re-easy-install'd the app.
This time, easy-install picked up that there was a 0.8 version, wiped the 0.7 version from wherever, and yay! all is well.

In case you want to do this super-manually though, try reading this stackoverflow item, which was of some use:
[Can we shed some definitive light on how python packaging and import works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714916/can-we-shed-some-definitive-light-on-how-python-packaging-and-import-works)

Answer (score 2):

I'd really recommend using pip and virtualenvs to manage your dependencies and paths. Things like this just disappear.

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/
http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: you're probably absolutely right. Sadly, i was just following the official doco for the django_registration installation - https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/fad7080fe769/docs/quickstart.rst - and had never heard of virualenvs. Lools nice, but i'm still left with my issue. Think i might just have to remove everything, get it again and get my code back from svn.

Answer (score 0):

I would use grep or ack to find where the path is set. On Windows, you could try http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm